# prevent copy+paste for TextArea()

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

How to prevent ctrl+v paste for flash.display.textarea()?

field.selectable = false; does not seem to work, also it disables caret/cursor

Comment: I doubt this is possible as it's default behavior for text input boxes and it's probably built into the flash player to implicity accept pastes from the various operating systems it supports.

Comment: I am trying to use this
evt.preventDefault () ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this seem to work in TextEvent listener,  any comments is it too bad solution to avoid copy+paste to a field ?

```
if (evt.text.length >1) 
evt.preventDefault () ;
```

Answer (score 1):

A TextArea is an editable textfield. You should use another component if you want to prevent copy / paste.

Answer (score 1):

The TextArea component has a textField property.  Setting the mouseEnabled property of the textField should have the desired effect.

```
var ta:TextArea = new TextArea();
ta.textField.mouseEnabled = false;
```

This disables the caret cursor and prevents selection of the text.

Answer (score 0):

If you can, use a different component instead of TextArea, as monkee [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/536588/prevent-copypaste-for-textarea/540692#540692).

If you're really into protecting against copying your text data you might even want to consider drawing the text on a canvas directly so it's really impossible to grab it unless the user does OCR or something.

Comment: any ideas where I can find such a component, actionscript3?

Answer (score 0):

We have another solution for it

```
field.mouseChildren = false;
```

so it will not allow to copy the data

Comment: `mouseChildren` is not a property of the TextField class. It's true that setting `mouseChildren` to `false` on the parent of a textfield will stop you being able copy the text with your mouse, but you could still copy using shift and copy/paste shortcuts.